# How to create a new field in elasticsearch and import data from postges into it?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a big table in postgres having 200 columns and more than a million rows. I want to migrate this data into elasticsearch using logstash. I am currently migrating around 50 columns.

What I want to know is can I add the other columns later mapping them to an index in elasticsearch? For example, say I have 10 columns in postgres and I map 4 into elasticsearch. Can I add the other 6 columns along with their data later to elasticsearch on the same index?

My current logstash config file looks like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {

        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school"


        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"


        jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/karangupta/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.8.jar"


        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"

        jdbc_paging_enabled => true

        statement_filepath => "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/conf/myQuery.sql" 
    }
}


# output {
#     stdout { codec => json_lines }
# }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "schoolupdated"
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
            }
        }
```

The above config file works perfectly and adds the index. How can I add fields to this index later from postgres?

I am using postgres 11.4, elasticsearch 6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can as long elasticsearch will be provided with a id for each if the rows.

Just add

```
document_id => "%{uniqe_identifier_column_name_in_your_result}" #column name is case senitive
```

to the elasticsearch output plugin configuration.

If you execute the jdbc import again (now with new tables), new fields will be added to the existing documents by overwriting the old documents.

More details on this topic: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id

Have fun!